# non existent class:Encrypt CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

i am trying to use codeIgnier Ecrypt library,when i am trying to include the library to my constructor of class or autoload.php  its given me this error

```
 function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library("Encrypt");
}


non-existent class:Encrypt
```

any suggestion will approicated thanx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: Please add the code, which you are using to load Encrypt library

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to an insufficient permission error. Try setting the Encrypt.php file permission to 644 and try again.

```
chmod 644 system/libraries/Encrypt.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You Must set a key to your application/config/config.php, open the file and set:

```
 $config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";
```

Load it in controller using

```
 $this->load->library('encrypt');
```

Once loaded, the Encrypt library object will be available using:

```
 $this->encrypt
```